# best method for serving static pages hosted on s3 in rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a rails app which is dynamic and works well on it's own, but we also have an s3 bucket which has a bunch of html pages which are constantly updated and revised.

I'm looking for an overall solution which allows me to route requests to the static files for a large number of potential pages, but also use the app for dynamic pages. None of the static pages require a user login, but all of the dynamic pages require a user login.

We are also currently using heroku to serve the application which is something else to take into consideration.

What are some methods/gems/ideas for how to serve these static pages quickly on the same domain without interfering with the rest of the app?

Answer (score 0):

According to Heroku you have 3 options:

- You can use page_caching. `page_caching` has been removed from rails4 but is still available as an external gem [actionpack-page_caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching) but from what I see, does not work as expected in heroku (files are not persisted).
- You can use cache through HTTP headers (which actually caches data on the client)
- You can use [Rack::Cache](http://rtomayko.github.io/rack-cache/) as a reverse proxy.

I think the best solution for your matter is the third one. Heroku suggests that you use `Rack::Cache`. Of course you can combine that with the HTTP headers.

You can find more details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/caching-strategies) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31)